# Proving a bump function

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, proof-writing

Let $\phi$ be a bump function on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

How do I prove that the function $u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\phi(x,y)$d$y$ is a bump function on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: To be a bump function, it needs to be smooth and it needs to have compact support. I presume it is the smoothness that is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Arthur: There are several things that are giving me trouble and smoothness is one of them. I don't know how I must start the proof

Comment: This is the short version of how you do the proof: First, show that $u(x)$ has compact support. Then, show that $u(x)$ is smooth. That's it. Now, showing that it has compact support is not difficult, since the support of $u$ seems to be just the projection of the support of $\phi$ onto $\Bbb R^n$. I haven't quite cracked the smoothness myself yet.